# Snapshot of Firebase Realtime DB incomplete/missing several layers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I have data stored in a Firebase Realtime DB that includes several layers of nesting.  One layer includes a key value pair with a key "practices" corresponding to an array.

[image]

When I retrieve this data from FB as a snapshot, this layer's value shows up as `undefined`.  The snapshot isn't completely flattened, but this layer and anything below is lost.

[image]

Here is how I am retrieving the data:

```
loadLanguage({commit}, lang){
    console.log('will try to load: ' + lang)
    DB.ref(`by_language/${lang}`).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    console.log('snapshot value below is missing several layers')
    var data=snapshot.val()
    console.log(data)
    commit('LOAD_LANGUAGE', {data: data, language: lang})
    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the data in the snapshot is different than the data stored in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach` to retrieve the data:

```
loadLanguage({commit}, lang){
    console.log('will try to load: ' + lang)
    DB.ref(`by_language/${lang}`).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    console.log('snapshot value below is missing several layers')
    var data = snapshot.val()
    snapshot.forEach(function(subSnapshot){
    var subData = subSnapshot.val()
    console.log(data)
    commit('LOAD_LANGUAGE', {data: data, language: lang})
     });
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the values are still showing up as `undefined`. 
```snapshot value below is missing several layers store.js:266
{…}
​
ACT: {…}
​​
"ACT English": undefined```

Comment: Is `lang` equal to EN? Also before it u have `by_language` node? Please try adding another child `child("Act English")` and tell me what you get

Comment: Yes, in one case it's equal to 'EN', and in another case it's 'DE'.  Both result in the `undefined`.  Where should I add the child?  Do you mean `DB.ref(`by_language/${lang}`).child('ACT').child('ACT English')`?  I tried this and it logs the array value `practices` that should be in the data -- so apparently the data is retrieved successfully.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean, if you have both ACT English and ACT German then u can make it dynamic instead of static

Comment: But I dnt see a reason not to use child("Act English")

Comment: That's the way the data is structured, if you look at the picture of the firebase backend you can see that `ACT English` is a child of `ACT`.  I can't make it dynamic based on the language because I can't predict what the children of `EN` or `DE` are going to be.  And there won't be any child called `ACT German` -- there's actually supposed to be data called `ACT English` that is a child of `DE`.  What I need is to simply be able to get the entire nested object as a snapshot, and I can't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Can u try this `loadLanguage({commit}, lang){
    console.log('will try to load: ' + lang)
    DB.ref(`by_language/${lang}`).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    console.log('snapshot value below is missing several layers')
    var data = snapshot.val()
    snapshot.forEach(function(subSnapshot){
   subSnapshot.forEach(function(snap){
     var datas = snap.val()
    console.log(datas)
    commit('LOAD_LANGUAGE', {data: data, language: lang})
     });
    });
  });
}`

Comment: `console.log(datas)` outputs the `practices` array, which is what is left out of the snapshot.

Comment: I appreciate the help but this doesn't actually answer my question.  `LOAD_LANGUAGE` is still being called with `data` that contains `undefined`, and more importantly, I don't know why Firebase's `once` function is returning incomplete data.  As I said before, I don't know how the data will be structured, so I can't just keep writing sub snapshots to the nth degree to get data that should be included in a snapshot in the first place.  I don't know how deep the nesting will be.

Comment: You shouldn't nest data in firebase database. That's bad practice, because if you do you will have this current problem that you are in. You need to change the database so it can be easily queried https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure